# Filter and display an ArcGIS ImageServer service by an attribute in an Desktop Addin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-image-server

What I am trying to achieve is to either filter an existing ArcGIS imageserver service, or get the results of a query and display them. The reason I want to do this is that I have a huge mosaic dataset and I want to display individual Map-Sheets (cause sometimes they even overlap).

By using this code I manage to connect to the service, query the desired image and get its attributes.

```
      IImageServer3 imageServer3 = (IImageServer3)GetImageServer("http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:6080/arcgis/services", "ServiceFolder/Sample Service", false);

                IQueryFilter attFilter = new ImageQueryFilterClass();
                attFilter.WhereClause = "Name = '0212043980'";

                int count = imageServer3.GetCatalogItemCount(attFilter);
                MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

With this I download the desired image and then I add it as a layer.

```
       var fff = imageServer3.GetCatalogItemIDs(attFilter);
                System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
```

`IImageServerDownloadResults isDownloadResults = imageServer3.Download(fff,
                null, null);

            IImageServerDownloadResult isDownloadResult;
            string url, fileName;
            for (int i = 0; i < isDownloadResults.Count; i++)
            {
                isDownloadResult = isDownloadResults.get_Element(i);
                url = imageServer3.GetFile(isDownloadResult);
                fileName = "c:\\temp\\" + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
            }`

But the thing is that I do not want to download the image (because most of the time the images are huge) I just want to display that **single image** it as a service.

I've done this in the past using the JavaScript web API, but I can't really understand if there is a way to do it on a desktop addin or not.

**the reason I am doing this is that I want to create a custom user friendly search engine for a huge mosaic dataset**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days I figured out a solution...I got no idea if its optimal...but it does exactly what I want...

```
    //GLOBAL
    static IEnvelope _envpoint = new EnvelopeClass();
    IImageServer3 _imageServer3 =
        (IImageServer3)
            GisHelper.GetImageServer("http://IP:6080/arcgis/services",
                "Folder/MosaicDataset", false);

    //CODE IN the FUNCTION
                string namestr = name.ToString();
                IQueryFilter attFilter = new ImageQueryFilterClass();
                attFilter.WhereClause = "Name = '" + namestr + "'";

                IRecordSet items = _imageServer3.GetCatalogItems(attFilter);

                ICursor pCursor = items.Table.Search(null, false);
                IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
                List<string> valuecollection = new List<string>();
                while (pRow != null)
                {
                    var t = pRow.get_Value(1);
                    var ddd = ((IGeometry) t);
                    _envpoint = ddd.Envelope;
                    pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
                }

                 var twidth = 800;
                var bts = ExportMapImageUrl(_imageServer3, items, twidth);
                if (_envpoint != null)
                {
                Bitmap bitmapp;

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bts))
                {
                    bitmapp = new Bitmap(ms);
                }
```

For some reason it needs a path that you can read and write but it doesn't seem to use it in any way since the image is created on memory

```
                var commonappdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
                var rasterds = CreateRasterDataset(commonappdata + "\\",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhmmss") + ".tiff", bitmapp);
                IRasterLayer pRastrLyr = new RasterLayerClass();
                pRastrLyr.CreateFromDataset(rasterds);
                var pSatelitelyr = (ILayer) pRastrLyr;
                pSatelitelyr.Name = "Raster Layer Name";
                ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.AddLayer(pSatelitelyr);
```

ExportMapImageUrl function

```
    public static byte[] ExportMapImageUrl(IImageServer imageServer, IRecordSet items, int thumbwidth)
    {
        ICursor pCursor = items.Table.Search(null, false);
        IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
        IImageServer2 imageServer2 = (IImageServer2)imageServer;
        IMosaicRule mosaicRule = new MosaicRuleClass();
        mosaicRule.MosaicMethod = esriMosaicMethod.esriMosaicLockRaster;
        mosaicRule.LockRasterID = pRow.get_Value(0).ToString();
        mosaicRule.MosaicOperatorType = rstMosaicOperatorType.MT_MAX;

        IGeoImageDescription2 geoImageDesc = new GeoImageDescriptionClass();
        geoImageDesc.PixelType = rstPixelType.PT_UCHAR;
        var wdim = (_envpoint.XMax - _envpoint.XMin) / thumbwidth;

        geoImageDesc.Height = Convert.ToInt32((_envpoint.YMax - _envpoint.YMin)/wdim);
        geoImageDesc.Width = thumbwidth;
        geoImageDesc.Interpolation = rstResamplingTypes.RSP_BilinearInterpolation;
        geoImageDesc.NoData = 0;
        geoImageDesc.Extent = _envpoint;
        geoImageDesc.MosaicRule = mosaicRule;

        IImageType imgType = new ImageTypeClass();
        imgType.Format = esriImageFormat.esriImageJPGPNG;
        imgType.ReturnType = esriImageReturnType.esriImageReturnMimeData;
        IMapImage mapImage = imageServer2.ExportMapImage(geoImageDesc, imgType);

        return mapImage.MimeData;
    }
```

Create Raster Dataset in Memory

```
         public static IRasterDataset CreateRasterDataset(string Path, string FileName, Bitmap bts)
    {
        try
        {
            IRasterWorkspace2 rasterWs = OpenRasterWorkspace(Path);
            ISpatialReference sr = new UnknownCoordinateSystemClass();
            IPoint origin = new PointClass();
            origin.PutCoords(_envpoint.XMin, _envpoint.YMin);

            int width = bts.Width; 
            int height = bts.Height;
            double xCell = (_envpoint.XMax - _envpoint.XMin) / width;
            double yCell = (_envpoint.YMax - _envpoint.YMin) / height;
            int NumBand = 3; 
            //MEM is memory
            IRasterDataset rasterDataset = rasterWs.CreateRasterDataset(FileName, "MEM",
                origin, width, height, xCell, yCell, NumBand, rstPixelType.PT_UCHAR, sr,
                true);

            IRasterBandCollection rasterBands = (IRasterBandCollection)rasterDataset;
            IRasterBand rasterBand;
            IRasterProps rasterProps;
            rasterBand = rasterBands.Item(0);
            rasterProps = (IRasterProps)rasterBand;

            rasterProps.NoDataValue = 255;

            IRaster raster = rasterDataset.CreateDefaultRaster();

            IPnt blocksize = new PntClass();
            blocksize.SetCoords(width, height);
            IPixelBlock3 pixelblock = raster.CreatePixelBlock(blocksize) as IPixelBlock3;

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                var pixels = (Array)pixelblock.PixelData[k];
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                    {
                        if (k == 0)
                        {
                            pixels.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(bts.GetPixel(i, j).R), i, j);
                        }

                        if (k == 1)
                        {
                            pixels.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(bts.GetPixel(i, j).G), i, j);
                        }

                        if (k == 2)
                        {
                            pixels.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(bts.GetPixel(i, j).B), i, j);
                        }
                    }
                }
                pixelblock.PixelData[k]= pixels;
            }
            IPnt upperLeft = new PntClass();
            upperLeft.SetCoords(0, 0);
            IRasterEdit rasterEdit = (IRasterEdit)raster;
            rasterEdit.Write(upperLeft, (IPixelBlock)pixelblock);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rasterEdit);

            return rasterDataset;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new instance of type **MosaicRuleClass** and assign it to your **IImageServerLayer**.

```
IImageServerLayer imageserverlayer = CreateSecuredISLayer(@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx:6080/arcgis/services", "Folder/mydata");

IMosaicRule mosaicRule = new MosaicRuleClass();
mosaicRule.MosaicMethod = esriMosaicMethod.esriMosaicLockRaster;
mosaicRule.LockRasterID = "615";
mosaicRule.MosaicOperatorType = rstMosaicOperatorType.MT_MAX;
IImageServerLayer3 isLayer = imageserverlayer as IImageServerLayer3;
isLayer.MosaicRule = mosaicRule;

ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.AddLayer(imageserverlayer);
```

Set the LockRasterID with the selected OID of your raster. That's all

Comment: This is indeed a neat solution but for some reason it does not work on Cached Mosaic Datasets. It gives a Catastrophic Failure error, which is indeed weird cause in a non-cashed dataset I tried it, it does work. I cannot grasp the reason why though.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned ,

> I want just to display it as a service.

To display an image service, you should create an image layer and then you can add this layer to the map or show it in a list. Then the user can manually do analysis with Arcmap (Clip,Attribute or Spatial Query,...)

- For services without authentication:

```cs
public static IImageServerLayer AccessImageServerLayer(string agsUrl="http://server/arcgis/services/serviceName/imageserver")
{
    //Create an image server layer by passing a URL.
    IImageServerLayer imageserverlayer = new ImageServerLayerClass(); 
    imageserverlayer.Initialize(agsUrl); 
    return imageserverlayer;
}
```

- For services that require https/authentication, use the following

```cs
IImageServerLayer imageserverlayer = CreateSecuredISLayer(@"http://server:6080/arcgis/services", "serviceName");

private static IImageServerLayer CreateSecuredISLayer(string agsUrl, string serviceName)
{
    IName soname = GetImageServerName(agsUrl, serviceName);
    IImageServerLayer isLayer = new ImageServerLayerClass();
    IDataLayer data_islayer = (IDataLayer)isLayer;
    data_islayer.DataSourceName = soname;
    return isLayer;
}


private static IName GetImageServerName(string hostOrUrl, string serviceName)
{
    IPropertySet propSet = new PropertySetClass();
    propSet.SetProperty("url", hostOrUrl);
    propSet.SetProperty("ANONYMOUS", false);
    //don't hardcode user/password
    //propertySet.SetProperty("user", userName);
    //propertySet.SetProperty("password", password);
    IAGSServerConnectionName agsServerConnectName = new AGSServerConnectionNameClass
        ();
    agsServerConnectName.ConnectionProperties = propSet;
    IAGSServerObjectName agsSOName = new AGSServerObjectNameClass();
    agsSOName.AGSServerConnectionName = agsServerConnectName;
    agsSOName.Name = serviceName;
    agsSOName.Type = "ImageServer";
    return (IName)agsSOName;
}
```

Comment: I got multiple ImageServer Layers which all require tokens as an authentication, I got that part solved and I already display several of them. The problem is that from a couple of those I dont want to display the entire mosaic dataset but a single image within that mosaic dataset.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear from the title Ill edit the post so as to be more clear

Comment: IMosaicRule interface defines the mosaic rule for mosaicking requested images on the fly. It contains a mosaic method, its parameters, and a mosaic operation. In general, a mosaic rule is used to specify (1) ***the selection of rasters to participate in the mosaic;*** (2) how the selected rasters are ordered; (3) how overlapping pixels at the same location are resolved.
[Sample Code],(http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000028z000000)


Maybe this is what you are looking for!

Comment: the thing is that this returns a url with the image (I tried it and I do get the image successfully, when i paste the url in a browser), again (as far as I can understand) how can i add this as a layer without downloading the image.